# is it atomic stack-update in aws cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, devops

Let's say I have a stack consisting of

1. ec2 instances as an application server
2. one ELB as a load balancer
3. two Elasticsearch nodes

Then, if I update the stack for any reason, maybe to increase the number of the application servers, are all the new components made ready in parallel to my current stack and my current stack is replaced with the new one at once, like atomic operations in database systems?

Because this reduction involves de-sharding the existing data in Elasticsearch, does the same procedure applies even if I reduce the number of Elasticsearch nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do a stack update, only the resources that you change will be [updated or replaced](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-updating-stacks.html). In your use case, if you make a change to the number of nodes in your ES cluster, your EC2 instances and ELB will remain in place and unchanged.

If you want to check which resources will be affected by changes that you have made to your template, you can use [CloudFormation Change Sets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-updating-stacks-changesets.html) to preview the changes before you apply them.

If you are just adding to the number of instances in your Auto Scaling Group, the existing ones will remain there. However, if you are reducing the number of instances in your ASG, the oldest will be removed first. You can use an [AutoScalingRollingUpdate policy](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/auto-scaling-group-rolling-updates/) to gain control over that.

Alternatively, you can specify to replace your entire ASG by with a new one, including all new EC2 instances, when updates are performed. Using an [AutoScalingReplacingUpdate policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-updatepolicy.html) you can configure this behaviour.

Comment: what happens when I am adding two new components and an error occurs while setting up the second component after the first component is successfully set-up? Will Cloudformation rollback the first component and my previous stack will stay intact?

Comment: Your stack will roll back and your existing resources will remain unchanged. You should see no interruptions to your services. When the stack is rolled back, it will change status to `UPDATE_FAILED_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE`. From that state, you can just fix your error and redeploy.